# How to put text on multiple images using python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import glob
import os
images = glob.glob("directory_path/*.jpg")

for img in images:
    images = Image.open(img)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(images)
    font = ImageFont.load_default() #Downloaded Font from Google font
    text = "Text on all images from directory"
    draw.text((0,150),text,(250,250,250),font=font)
    images.save(img)
```

**I have to put text on all images , I have tried above code but its not working**

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me just fine, but the text was hard to read because it was small and white. I did change `directory_path` to `images` and put my images in there. The images looked like this, the text is small and on the left side:
[image: banana with text]

Answer (score 0):

one possible problem with the code may be that you are using the images variable for saving the list of images and also to iterate through the images.
Try this code, this will work for sure.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import glob
import os
images = glob.glob("new_dir/*.jpg")
print(images)

for img in images:
    image = Image.open(img)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    font = ImageFont.load_default() #Downloaded Font from Google font
    text = "Text on all images from directory"
    draw.text((0,150),text,fill = 'red' ,font=font)
    image.save(img)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the solution**

```
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw,ImageFont
import glob
import os

images=glob.glob("path/*.jpg")

for img in images:
    images=Image.open(img)
    draw=ImageDraw.Draw(images)
    font=ImageFont.load_default()
    text="Whatever text"
    draw.text((0,240),text,(250,250,250),font=font)
    images.save(img)
```